# What does "do sea on classes" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-play

I see this sentence on https://twitter.com/jfbastien/status/1003697787911966720

> A: I've made my submissions for @cpponsea, have you?
>
> B: Sorry, I only do **Sea** on Classes
>
> C: you can do classes on the sea at C++ on **Sea** - and in class, too

Google tells me nothing: [do sea](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+sea&oq=do+sea&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j69i59j69i60j69i61j0.4704j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) [do sea on class](https://www.google.com/search?q=do+Sea+on+class&oq=do+sea+&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i61j69i57j69i60j69i61j0.2673j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a joke, a pun based on the fact that C (the programming language) and "sea" sound the same.

There is going to be a conference C++ on Sea, in a coastal town (some coastal towns have the suffix -on-sea, eg Southend-on-sea). The pun is then continued, as "on the sea" means in a boat; C++ has classes but C does not.

So if you were programming in C++, in a classroom on a boat, while attending the conference you could be said to be doing "classes on the sea at C++ on Sea - and in class".

Comment: So, **sea** here can mean **C** or **sea**, as well as, **class** here can mean**class(keyword in c++)** or **class(room)**, right? Can you help me rewrite what B and C said with `classroom`, `class(keyword in c++)`, `C`, `sea`(I still a little confused which should be which, thanks!

Comment: The point of a pun is that a word is used with multiple meanings. So it is impossible to give just one meaning to a pun.

Comment: Also, "C with Classes" was the name of what later became C++ :)